# Import Cinema 4D animations to three.js (via the WEBGL Renderer)

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, cinema-4d

G’day

I’m planning on making a looping animation in C4D, being sure to texture the model via uv maps and pbr textures made in substance painter. I’m going to use voroni fracture if that bring up any complications.

I want to import a c4d animation to three.js via the WebGL Renderer

Im not that experienced with C4D nor javascript but I’ve got a deadline to finish my website in 5 days so im hoping that you guys could help me out.

I know there’s an easy method when importing animations from blender to a website via three.js but i dont know of any methods from c4d… I know my terminology is rough, im a beginner and really want to get this done by tomorrow. I’m also not sure on the export settings for the animation.

**THREE.js Website:** http://threejs.org/

Cheers guys (I know i’m very very inexperienced so sorry in advance for the troubles. The way i’ve described what im after is very bare bones so sorry about that)

Comment: I don't think there's a c4d loader available for three.js.. If you could export to gltf or Collada it would be so much easier. https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Comment: @EthanHermsey I know you can export c4d models via a gltf plugin and i know how to import them via three.js, i'm just not sure on how it would work with animations as well as how to properly optimize the animation for interactive viewing on a website with all the baked textures optimized with the animation. (by interactive i basically mean rotate the model in all 3 axis.

Comment: For gtlf models I've previously used the animation blending method from this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=animation#webgl_animation_skinning_blending  You could use it to cycle though all animation. You could use a THREE.OrbitControl for the rotating (you will have to add https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js to your files). That should run pretty smoothly.